# Creating an sqlite database with a diff file

Tags: python, sql, database, sqlite, diff

I need to create an sqlite database with data from a diff file. The diff file has 10 columns (and more than a thousand rows). I only want the 1st, 6th, 7th, 8th, and 10th columns to go into the database. How can I do this without having to add each row individually?

I have created the database:

```
import sqlite3
connection = sqlite3.connect('genes.db')
cursor=connection.cursor()
```

Now I am stuck on how I can proceed from here.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should do it, but it depends on what your diff output looks like

```
import sqlite3
connection = sqlite3.connect('genes.db')
cursor = connection.cursor()

# create a table for inserting the data
create = ('CREATE TABLE genes (A text, B text, C text, D text, E text)')
cursor.execute(create)


difffile = """\
one two three four five six seven eight nine ten
a b c d e f g h i j
k l m n o p q r s t\
"""

# rows list for storing the data to insert
rows = []

# loop over lines in difffile
for line in difffile.split("\n"):

    # split the current line by whitespace
    fields = line.split()

    # skip over lines with less than 10 columns
    if len(fields) < 10:
        continue

    # columns we want
    cols = (1, 6, 7, 8, 10)

    # create a row tuple with the data we want
    row = tuple([fields[col - 1] for col in cols])

    # add the current row to our rows list
    rows.append(row)

# insert row list into the database table "genes"
cursor.executemany("INSERT INTO genes VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", rows)

# test the insert by dumping the database table genes:
results = cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM genes")
for r in results.fetchall():
    print(r)
```

This will show the data from the columns we want has been inserted, producing the output:

```
(u'one', u'six', u'seven', u'eight', u'ten')
(u'a', u'f', u'g', u'h', u'j')
(u'k', u'p', u'q', u'r', u't')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for responding! This may seem like a silly question, but what are you doing in the "difffile =" step?

Comment: Hi, no problem.  In that line I am simulating the data that would be returned from reading the diff file so that my example would work for demonstration purpose.  To open an actual file, replace the line with `difffile = open("filename").read()`

Comment: Thanks for that tip! 
After doing row.append, I am seeing the following message. 
IndexError: list index out of range

Do you have any idea what is going wrong?

Comment: I don't think you can get an IndexError from an append operation.  It's probably due to the preceeding line ```row = tuple([fields[col - 1] for col in cols])``` and probably because there is a line with less than ten columns, or the columns are not separated by whitespace.  I would need to see a few lines of the diff file to know.

Comment: Here is a link to an image showing the first few lines of the file:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5d4EVStgOCSUThOX0k3YkVDdHc/edit?usp=sharing
I can't seem to post images here directly.

Comment: From that sample it looks ok, there are more than ten columns in each line and they are separated by whitespace.  Try adding a line; `print(fields)` after the line `fields = line.split()` to see where it's going wrong.  Perhaps there is a blank line at the end of the file?

Comment: I have modified the answer to skip over lines with less than 10 columns

Comment: I tried this, but now I am getting a new error: TypeError: object of type 'bool' has no len()    
Doing a print(fields) earlier showed [] at the end. Is there a way to just remove that line?

Comment: My bad!  The line I added closed the parenthesis in the wrong place.  It should have been: `if len(fields) < 10:`.  I have updated my answer again to correct this.  So it should work even with the blank line at the end.